# Running Batch with accdb action within as a Scheduled Task

Tags: batch-file, ms-access, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a batch which is doing several things.
When i create a schedular task the batch will execute all the lines till the access action, then he won't respond anymore... Am i doing something wrong? The program is nog giving any error and the status of the schedular task still is "running" It is running on a server. When i manually activate the batch it all works perfectly...

```
Y:
Timeout 2
if exist Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\8001346.xls del Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\8001346.xls /q

Timeout 1

if exist Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\*.xls* MOVE Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\*.xls* Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\Afgemaakt\

COPY Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Nieuw\*.xls* Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerken\Matrix.txt
COPY Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Nieuw\*.txt Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerken\Matrix.txt

Timeout 5

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "W:\Matrix.accdb" "/XAanmaak en Export Excel netto Matrix"

Timeout 120

COPY Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerken\Matrix.xls Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\Matrix.xls

Timeout 2

del Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerken\matrix.txt /q
del Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerken\matrix.xls /q

if exist Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Verwerkt\combi-lijst.xls goto Einde

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "W:\Matrix.accdb" "/XAanmaak en Export Excel combis Matrix"

:Einde

del Y:\ASCII\Matrix\Ombouwen\Nieuw\*.txt /q
```

Answer (score 0):

The leading "/X" looks strange, and no quotes if I recall correctly. Thus:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "W:\Matrix.accdb" /x Aanmaak en Export Excel netto Matrix
```

or don't use spaces:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" "W:\Matrix.accdb" /x Aanmaak_en_Export_Excel_netto_Matrix
```

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then it probably is a question about user rights. Is the user account running the batch logged on?

Comment: Whether it is logged on or not

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you use network drives in your batch. If so, it doesn't work because Schedule service logged by default under Local System account, which doesn't have access rights to network drives. Change default account to any other user's account, which has rights on network shares.

Comment: The most weird about it is that we have other batches with access databases and they are working!.....

Comment: exactly the same drive but another access database

Comment: Can you see the window of running database? Probably it returns an error, but you don't see it. Try to create a macro, which just quits the database and use it in batch command line instead of current one. If the task completed successfully, the problem in macro

Comment: I now created a batch with a macro of just closing it. When i mannually start it, it works but not with schedular task

Comment: Strange. I would try to replace whole db by db, which works in another batch and vice versa - not working db to working batch - to understand where is problem, in batch or in db.

Comment: You said, that you have another db, which works fine in another scheduled batch. Exchange database files between batches

Comment: @Serger S. So what you are saying is that i should combine the databases?

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should combine the databases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114808/discussion-between-sergey-s-and-j-cup).